# Accessing a local access database from Flash (or AIR)

Tags: database, flash, actionscript-3, ms-access, air

Is it possible for Flash or possibly Adobe AIR to have access to a local Access database?

I will have either a Flash EXE or AIR application running on a local PC (WinXP). The PC will also have a local Access database. I need my Flash application to get the data from this Access database. How would I do this?

I doubt it can be done with Flash or AIR alone (someone prove me wrong or right), but is there an option for some middle-man application to access the data base and send it on to Flash? How would this work?

Or could I read the MDB file into Flash and parse it myself? is there a library for this?

Comment: Have you checked if you can use ODBC or OLEDB? If so, you the Jet or ACE drivers for these should work, depending on the Access version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access a local Access database you would have to write some kind of service that can be called by air/flex. You can access a SqLite database with AS3 library, so maybe you can convert your access database into a SqLite database.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up getting a co-worker to write a .NET service that I can poll from my Flash EXE. The service then returns the amount of entries requested.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it with AIR alone (unless there is an AS3 library for parsing access DB). However, you can connect with the db using an AIR - Java bridge like [merapi](http://code.google.com/p/merapi/).

> Merapi allows developers to connect Adobe AIR applications, written in Adobe Flex to Java applications running on the user's local computer.

PS: A quick search shows that there is an [AS3 library for MySQL](http://code.google.com/p/assql/).